# Removing special keyboard characters/shapes with regex or?

Tags: php, regex

I am using YQL to scrape some data, and then parsing it into Amazon's simpledb.  I am getting some errors when attempting to insert certain titles into the DB, because some titles from the xml file that I am parsing contain characters like the one's below.

```
◆ ▒ ♠ ✖ ¸ . ´ ¨
```

I am sure that's not all the possible special characters.  It's just the one's I've noticed so far that are causing the errors.

These are not standard keyboard characters.  Is there a simple way to remove/disallow these types of characters (regex, etc..) without finding every one of them and including them in a regex?

Thanks

Comment: Which errors do you get? Not that you're changing titles only because you're looking on the wrong end, because a database should accept those characters, too.

Comment: I am using http://webmasterinresidence.ca/simpledb/ to insert the parsed data into the DB.  Not sure if it's just that php script returning the errors or simpledb is refusing and reporting the error back to the script.

Comment: `putAttributes() item knoxville-2799200717Item`
`knoxville-2799200717 FAILED`
`ErrorCode: InvalidParameterValue`

That's an example of the error.  Other items where no special characters are included are input into the DB without errors.

Comment: I have tried using a script to remove invalid utf-8 characters, but I get the same result.
`preg_match_all('/([\x09\x0a\x0d\x20-\x7e]'. // ASCII characters
 '|[\xc2-\xdf][\x80-\xbf]'. // 2-byte (except overly longs)
 '|\xe0[\xa0-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]'. // 3 byte (except overly longs)
 '|[\xe1-\xec\xee\xef][\x80-\xbf]{2}'. // 3 byte (except overly longs)
 '|\xed[\x80-\x9f][\x80-\xbf])+/', // 3 byte (except UTF-16 surrogates)
 $input, $clean_pieces );

$clean_output = join('?', $clean_pieces[0] );`
http://webcollab.sourceforge.net/unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]/s', '', $text);
```

This will trim your text so it only contains letters or numbers, spaces and underlines/dashes.

***Reference*** http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=223131.0

Comment: I may end up using this and just adding some other characters.  Thanks